# Bluetooth headphones pause/play button not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pulseaudio, bluetooth, manjaro, bluez

I've been trying to get the pause/play button on my headphones working (Plantronics BackBeat Pro 2) with my laptop running Manjaro 17.1.10. They also have Next and Previous buttons which work perfectly fine. I've tried them in Spotify, Clementine, and VLC with the same results.

I've read the  Arch wiki pages for:

- [Pulseaudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio)
- [Bluetooth headset](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset)
- [Extra keyboard keys in Xorg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_keyboard_keys_in_Xorg)

From what I've found it looks like I need to load the `uinput` kernel module. The guides that I read say they should go in two different places and neither one explains waht to put in.

*/etc/rc.conf*

*/etc/modules-load.d/uinput.conf \<-- (I think this is for a Legacy method?)*

This is what I got while trying to find it:

```
[ibro@ibro-pc ~]$ lsmo |grep uinput
bash: lsmo: command not found
[ibro@ibro-pc ~]$ lsmod |grep uinput
uinput                 20480  1
[ibro@ibro-pc ~]$ grep uinput /proc/modules
uinput 20480 1 - Live 0xffffffffc048d000
[ibro@ibro-pc ~]$ grep uinput /proc/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin
grep: /proc/4.14.40-1-MANJARO/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
[ibro@ibro-pc ~]$ pulseaudio --version
pulseaudio 11.1
```

So assuming this is the problem I need to figure out where ans how to add `uinput` 
If not a solution for whatever else it might be

There are two additional headphone features I would like to add support for in linux.

- Smart-pause when they are taken of and continue playing when put on
- Active Listening Mode: pauses music when sound is detected.

Both of the these have very similar output to pause/play button when I run `xev`

```
KeyPress event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x8800001,
    root 0x16a, subw 0x0, time 13766406, (-871,191), root:(420,262),
    state 0x0, keycode 209 (keysym 0x1008ff31, XF86AudioPause), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x8800001,
    root 0x16a, subw 0x0, time 13766437, (-871,191), root:(420,262),
    state 0x0, keycode 209 (keysym 0x1008ff31, XF86AudioPause), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x8800001,
    root 0x16a, subw 0x0, time 13767016, (-871,191), root:(420,262),
    state 0x0, keycode 208 (keysym 0x1008ff14, XF86AudioPlay), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 172
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x8800001,
    root 0x16a, subw 0x0, time 13767047, (-871,191), root:(420,262),
    state 0x0, keycode 208 (keysym 0x1008ff14, XF86AudioPlay), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 172
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

This is the actual keyboard pause/play buton

```
FocusIn event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x8800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusOut event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x8800001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusOut event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x8800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

FocusIn event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x8800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: [Related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/649461/428315) on askubuntu which points to [this Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1397142).

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6642/buttons-on-my-bluetooth-headset-arent-working